# draw io dynamically adjust background rectangle

Tags: draw.io

I have two lists that I have placed on top of a rectangle. The rectangle is proportional in size to the two lists and can be considered a background for them.

I want the rectangle to adjust its size when the lists are expanded and the lists must move when they are expanded as well. So I want them to act like this:
[image: Before expanding]

[image: After expanding]

Where we can see that the rectangle was adjusted in size after expansion and Testing List 2 was moved more to the bottom after expansion of Testing List 1.

Can this be done? And if so, how?

If it helps: the width always stays the same, its only the height that needs to be adjusted. Same goes for the positioning: only the vertical position of the second list must be able to change.